# Why is there a GUID added to devenv.exe in the UAC prompt window?

Tags: windows-10, uac, file-shortcut

I have a shortcut to Visual Studio 2013 in my taskbar's quick start area. The target exe is named `devenv.exe`, but when I right-click it and *Run as administrator*, the UAC prompt that opens has a GUID added to the exe name. Why?

UAC prompt:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 devenv.exe UAC prompt with GUID]

Shortcut properties:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 devenv.exe shortcut properties]

Comment: Go to the target file’s details and you can probably find your answer.

Comment: @DanielB no, there isn't anything there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have VS2015 Community installed.  When I run is as administrator the UAC prompt says "devenv_80af265e-a92b-4324-ab32-c46fe27cebf2.exe".

What's shown to you in the UAC prompt is either the file name, or if the signer provided a description, that's what will be displayed instead.

This is the case with DevEnv.exe, MS signs with a description that includes the file name plus a "random" string of characters (not really sure how random it is between versions/computers).

If I use MS' [SignTool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz(v=vs.110).aspx) to [verify the file signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa388171.aspx) on DevEnv.exe and view the assigned description it reports (in part):

(Command used: `signtool.exe /v /pa /d devenv.exe`)

```
Description:     devenv_80af265e-a92b-4324-ab32-c46fe27cebf2.exe
Description URL: http://microsoft.com


Successfully verified: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

And low and behold the Description matches what the UAC prompt shows.

Why MS chose to use this format for the description of DevEnv.exe I'm not sure, nor can I find any reference to it.

Comment: This is it. Could you please add the command line you used? I can't get it to output the description. Interestingly, the SignTool description is in fact a different description than the "File description" from the *Properties* - *Details* tab and isn't even part of the `VERSIONINFO` (or any other resource), which is what is usually displayed in the UAC prompt.

Comment: Added the command I used (minus paths to the various files).  Re your comment:  "File description" = Description of file.  Description in the UAC/Signtool = "description of the signed content". :)